# bash history not being preserved

Tags: 12.10, bash, bashrc

this is a fresh install of ubuntu 12.10. i haven't even looked at the bashrc or profile files when i noticed that

- history would work fine for the current session.
- as soon as i closed the terminal, all history was gone

my first reaction was to check some new default `.bash_logout` but there's nothing there besides a line to clear the screen. i commented it out just to be sure.

then i checked all the system wide bash settings, such as `/etc/bashrc` and still nothing.

what may be happening here?

EDIT:
ok, found the issue... `.bash_history` was owned by root! only on the user that i created during the install. will install on another box with the same image to rule out a bug or a mistake on my part after the install.

Comment: Please report the edit as an answer and mark it as accepted, if the issue is completely resolved.

Comment: So, i did more investigation. I have 3 boxes that i installed yesterday. this one (ubuntu 12.10) that i'm using. another (ubuntu 12.10) that i barely logged in, and one that is not really ubuntu but is close (mythubuntu 12.04)... on all 3, the main accounted had ~/.bash_history owned by root. If anyone else can confirm this happens i can file a proper bug. if not i will consider this is just me being dumb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed on new Ubuntu 12.10 i686 installation, with initial user account.

```
guinan@x100e:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.10, Quantal Quetzal"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu quantal (12.10)"
VERSION_ID="12.10"

guinan@x100e:~$ arch
i686

guinan@x100e:~$ ls -l .bash_history
-rw------- 1 root root 302 Mar 12 13:19 .bash_history

guinan@x100e:~$ less .bash_history
.bash_history: Permission denied

guinan@x100e:~$ rm .bash_history
rm: remove write-protected regular file `.bash_history'? y

$ xterm
[ $ echo Hi there. ]
[ $ exit ]


guinan@x100e:~$ ls -l .bash_history
-rw------- 1 guinan guinan 15 Mar 13 13:48 .bash_history

guinan@x100e:~$ cat .bash_history 
echo Hi there.
```